# JPA polymorphic oneToMany

Tags: java, jpa, polymorphism

I couldn't figure out how to cleanly do a tag cloud with JPA where each db entity can have many tags.

E.g

Post can have 0 or more Tags
User can have 0 or more Tags

Is there a better way in JPA than having to make all the entities subclass something like Taggable abstract class? Where a a Tag entity would reference many Taggables.

Edit: the tag cloud is just a sample to simplify the problem I am having. In my scenario, the relation should be OneToMany where a Tag cannot be reused.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

This seems like ManyToMany, not one to Many.  Users can have multiple tags, and a tag can be associated with more than one user?

You would only need such a superclass if you want to be able to have a relationship on your Tag to a single collection that contains every object marked with that tag.  Do you have a requirement for a `tag.getOneGiantCollectionOfEveryTaggedEntity()` method?

Since the marked objects don't seem to otherwise have anything in common, does such a collection really have any value in your application domain?  It could also ostensibly be quite large and not something you'd really want to work with via object relationships anyway.  From a practical standpoint, without knowing about your use case, it seems like `tag.getTaggedUsers()`, `tag.getTaggedPosts()` etc are more useful.

Sorry, guess I'm asking more questions than giving answers, but it's not clear what you want your finished object domain to look like :)

edit:

Maybe the actual answer then to the question asked is just "No, Hibernate will not map for you you a Raw Collection of types with no common ancestor that just happen to all have foreign keys to your entity."  You don't neccessarily have to impose a 'fake' superclass on your entities, but if you don't then you'll have to make a join table.

.?

Comment: thx for the reply affe. I gave tag cloud as a sample to simply the problem. sorry, maybe it was not the best example. but ideally I would prefer OneToMany as in my scenario the "tag" is not reused and I want to avoid having additional join tables.

Comment: heh i should have read your comment before editing my answer to use @manyToMany then ;)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better way in JPA than having to make all the entities subclass something like Taggable abstract class?

Let's forget the example :) JPA does support polymorphic associations but the target classes have to be part of an inheritance hierarchy. And here are some more rules of thumb about inheritance strategies:

> - SINGLE_TABLE:
>
>   - All the classes in a hierarchy are mapped to a single table
>   - This strategy provides good support polymorphic relationships between
>       entities and queries that cover the
>       entire class hierarchy.
>   - May contain null fields for some subclass data
> - TABLE_PER_CLASS:
>
>   - Each class in a hierarchy mapped to a separate table and hence, provides
>       poor support for polymorphic
>       relationships
>   - requires SQL union or separate SQL queries for each subclass
> - JOINED
>
>   - no null fields => compact data
>   - This provides good support for polymorphic relationships, but
>       requires one or more join operations –
>       may result in poor performance

In short, if your subclasses declare relatively few properties, prefer the `SINGLE_TABLE` strategy. If not, use a `JOINED` strategy unless you have a deep hierarchy (in which case the cost of joins may become more expensive than unions and then `TABLE_PER_CLASS` would be "less worse").

#### References

- JPA 1.0 Specification

  - Section 2.1.9 "Inheritance"
  - Section 2.1.10 "2.1.10 Inheritance Mapping Strategies"

Answer (score 0):

why dont you just map a Collection of Tags or even Strings?

sudocode:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="entities")
class MyEntity{
    long id;
    String someField;
    @ManyToMany(targetEntity=Tag.class)
    @JoinTable(name="entities_to_tags",
         joinColumns={
             @JoinColumn(name="id",  
             referencedColumnName="entity_id",
             inverseJoinColumns={
                 @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="tag_id")})
    List<Tag> tags;
    [...getter&setter...]
}

@Entity
@Table(name="tags")
class Tag{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    long id;
    String title;
    [....getter & setter...]
}
```

Comment: thx for the response steve.
in your sample, Tag should hold a "join column" to MyEntity right? how is that going to work if if I have two taggable entities e.g MyEntity1 and MyEntity2.

Comment: like Affe elaborated you could just use @ManyToMany instead so youll get a relation table from MyEntity's PKs to Tag's PK.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need polymorphic queries such as "get everything tagged tagged Foo", then you can also introduce a new entity (say `TaggingTarget`), and create a unidirectional one-to-one relation from `User` (`Post`, etc) to `TaggingTarget` and many-to-many relation between `TaggingTarget` and `Tag`:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @OneToOne
    private TaggingTarget target;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class TaggingTarget {
    @ManyToMany(...)
    private Set<Tag> tags;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Tag {
    @ManyToMany(...)
    private Set<TagTarget> targets;
    ...
}
```

The difference from Affe's solution is that you don't need a `tag.getTaggedUsers()`, `tag.getTaggedPosts()`, etc and can add new tagged entities without changing `Tag`. Tagged entities can be queried using JPQL:

```
select u from User u where :tag member of u.target.tags
```

or

```
select u from User u join u.target.tags t where t.name = :name
```