# Hibernate - Persisting polymorphic joins

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to understand how to best implement a polymorphic one-to-many in hibernate.

Eg:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity  {
    Integer id;
    // etc...
}

@Entity
public class Author extends BaseEntity {}

@Entity
public class Post extends BaseEntity {}

@Entity
public class Comment extends BaseEntity {}
```

And now, I'd like to also persist audit information, with the following class:

```
@Entity
public class AuditEvent {
    @ManyToOne // ?
    BaseEntity entity;
}
```

What is the appropriate mapping for `auditEvent.entity`?  Also, how will Hibernate actually persist this?  Would a series of join tables be generated (`AuditEvent_Author` , `AuditEvent_Post`, `AuditEvent_Comment`), or is there a better way?

Note, I'd rather not have my other entity classes expose the other side of the join (eg., `List<AuditEvent> events` on `BaseEntity`) - but if that's the cleanest way to implement, then it will suffice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A mapped superclass is not an entity and thus can't be part of an association (as reminded in [EJB-199](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/EJB-199)). So either:

- make your `BaseEntity` abstract and use a `TABLE_PER_CLASS` strategy (see this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912988/persist-collection-of-interface-using-hibernate/2918468#2918468))
- introduce another `AuditableEntity` **entity** in the hierarchy and use what would be the most [appropriate inheritance strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914972/jpa-polymorphic-onetomany/2918513#2918513) for your use case.
- consider using [Envers](http://www.jboss.org/envers)