# Hibernate and Inheritance (TABLE_PER_CLASS)

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, orm, annotations

I use Hibernate to persist inherited objects but I got this message when I try to persist objects in database:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Could not execute
JDBC batch update; SQL [update Widget set CONTAINER_ID=? where WIDGET_ID=?]; nested 
exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: 
Could not execute JDBC batch update (...) Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Table 
'schema.widget' doesn't exist
```

Here is the classes I used to generate the table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CONTAINER")
public class Container {
     (...)
     private Set<Widget> widgets;

     @OneToMany(targetEntity = Widget.class)
     @JoinColumn(name="CONTAINER_ID", nullable=true)
     public Set<Widget> getWidgets() {
         return widgets;
     }

     public void setWidgets(Set<Widget> widgets) {
         this.widgets = widgets;
     }
}


@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Widget {
     private long id;
     private int position;

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
     @Column(name="WIDGET_ID")
     public long getId() {
         return id;
     }

     public void setId(long id) {
         this.id = id;
     }

     @Column(name="POSITION")
     public int getPosition() {
         return position;
     }

     public void setPosition(int position) {
         this.position = position;
     }
}


@Entity
@Table(name="TEXT_WIDGET")
public class TextWidget extends Widget {
     (...)
}


@Entity
@Table(name="IMAGE_WIDGET")
public class ImageWidget extends Widget {
     (...)
}
```

So it means that Hibernate is looking for the table 'widget' but it's not created and that make sense because I choose InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS option then only concrete classes have a table. In database, I can see container, text_widget and image_widget tables.

Then when I try to execute this code and save container, then I got the above error:

```
Set<Widget> widgets = new HashSet<Widget>();
widgets.add(textw1); // instance of TextWidget
widgets.add(imgw1); // instance of ImageWidget

Container container1 = new Container();
container1.setWidgets(widgets);
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7):

Your association must be  bidirectional, as mentioned in the Hibernate documentation.

> #### [2.2.4.1. Table per class](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1191)
>
> This strategy has many drawbacks (esp.
>   with polymorphic queries and
>   associations) explained in the JPA
>   spec, the Hibernate reference
>   documentation, Hibernate in Action,
>   and many other places. Hibernate work
>   around most of them implementing this
>   strategy using SQL UNION queries. It
>   is commonly used for the top level of
>   an inheritance hierarchy:
>
> ```
> @Entity
> @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
> public class Flight implements Serializable { ... }
> ```
>
> This strategy supports one-to-many
>   associations **provided that they are
>   bidirectional**. This strategy does
>   not support the IDENTITY generator
>   strategy: the id has to be shared
>   across several tables. Consequently,
>   when using this strategy, you should
>   not use AUTO nor IDENTITY.

This way, Hibernate will be able to create the appropriate foreign key column in each concrete widget table. Here is a mapping that actually works. For the `Container`:

```
@Entity
public class Container {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Widget.class, mappedBy = "container", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Widget> widgets = new HashSet<Widget>();

    public long getId() { return id; }

    public void setId(long id) { this.id = id; }

    public Set<Widget> getWidgets() { return widgets; }

    public void setWidgets(Set<Widget> widgets) { this.widgets = widgets; }

    public void addToWidgets(Widget widget) {
        this.getWidgets().add(widget);
        widget.setContainer(this);
    }

    public void removeFromWidgets(Widget widget) {
        this.getWidgets().remove(widget);
        widget.setContainer(null);
    }
}
```

And the abstract Widget class:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Widget {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private long id;

    private int position;

    @ManyToOne
    private Container container;

    public long getId() { return id; }

    public void setId(long id) { this.id = id; }

    public int getPosition() { return position; }

    public void setPosition(int position) { this.position = position; }

    public Container getContainer() { return container; }

    public void setContainer(Container container) { this.container = container; }
}
```

And the following test method (running inside a transaction) just passes:

```
@Test
public void testInsertContainer() {
    TextWidget textw1 = new TextWidget();
    ImageWidget imgw1 = new ImageWidget();

    Container container1 = new Container();
    container1.addToWidgets(textw1); // instance of TextWidget
    container1.addToWidgets(imgw1); // instance of ImageWidget

    session.persist(container1);
    session.flush();

    assertNotNull(textw1.getId());
    assertNotNull(imgw1.getId());
    assertNotNull(container1.getId());
}
```

And generates the following SQL:

```
21:59:57.964 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select next_hi from hibernate_unique_key for read only with rs
21:59:57.978 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - update hibernate_unique_key set next_hi = ? where next_hi = ?
21:59:58.063 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - null
21:59:58.125 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - insert into Container (id) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into Container (id) values (?)
21:59:58.140 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.LongType - binding '98304' to parameter: 1
21:59:58.145 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - insert into ImageWidget (container_id, position, id) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into ImageWidget (container_id, position, id) values (?, ?, ?)
21:59:58.164 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.LongType - binding '98304' to parameter: 1
21:59:58.165 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.IntegerType - binding '0' to parameter: 2
21:59:58.166 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.LongType - binding '32768' to parameter: 3
21:59:58.172 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - insert into TextWidget (container_id, position, id) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into TextWidget (container_id, position, id) values (?, ?, ?)
21:59:58.187 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.LongType - binding '98304' to parameter: 1
21:59:58.188 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.IntegerType - binding '0' to parameter: 2
21:59:58.189 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.LongType - binding '32769' to parameter: 3
```

But keep in mind that the *table per class* strategy provides **poor support for polymorphic relationships** and might not be appropriate at all if you have many `Widget` child (this will result in huge SQL UNION).

#### Related question

- [JPA polymorphic oneToMany](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914972/jpa-polymorphic-onetomany/2918513#2918513)