# TABLE_PER_CLASS Bidirectional @OneToMany Problem

Tags: hibernate, polymorphism, one-to-many

Hibernate can do bidirectional polymorphism with `TABLE_PER_CLASS` (`<union-subclass>`), says so [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1191):

> This strategy supports one-to-many associations provided that they are bidirectional.

I'm trying to get a simple example to work. 4 basic classes: *abstract* **A** <-- **B** <-- **C** and **A** <-- **D**, where D is holding `myArray` of B's.

I get no error; `myArray` is simply empty.

### Details

**A**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Class_A {
    @Id
    public int myId = 0;
    public int a = 0;
}
```

**B**

```
@Entity
public class Class_B extends Class_A {
    public int b = 0;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="join_column_b")
    private Class_D class_d;
}
```

**C**

```
@Entity
public class Class_C extends Class_B {
    public int c = 0;
}
```

**D**

```
@Entity
public class Class_D extends Class_A {
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="class_d", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    public List<Class_B> myArray;

    public Class_D() {
        myArray = new ArrayList<Class_B>();
    }
}
```

### Code

```
// Definition.
Class_B b = new Class_B(); b.myId =  9;
Class_C c = new Class_C(); c.myId = 18;
Class_D d = new Class_D(); d.myId = 92;
d.myArray.add(b);
d.myArray.add(c);

// Saving.
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
session.save(d);
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();

// Loading.
Session session2 = sessionFactory.openSession();
session2.beginTransaction();
Class_D d2 = (Class_D)session2.createQuery("from " + Class_D.class.getName()).uniqueResult();
session2.getTransaction().commit();
session2.close();
```

In the debugger I can compare instance `d` with `d2` (they are not the same instance, but have the same `myId`). `d2` has an empty `myArray`.

No exception - No Oracle error - No nothing

Why?

Notes:
 1. Hibernate 3.6.0 Final + Oracle 11g + pure Java
 2. Using annotations
 3. I've reviewed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557879/hibernate-and-inheritance-table-per-class) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914972/jpa-polymorphic-onetomany/2918513#2918513) but still can't get this simple example to work (*ffs!*)
 4. I'll be able to update next on Sunday - please forgive me if I don't reply until then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When saving relationship to the database Hibernate looks at the owning side. For bidirectional one-to-many relationships the owning side is "many", i.e. `Class_B` in your case.

Therefore database reflects state of `Class_B.class_d`, and you should set its value when associating `Class_B` to `Class_D` (it would be better to create a method to set both sides at once):

```
public class Class_D {
    ...
    public void addToMyArray(Class_B class_b) {
        myArray.add(class_b);
        class_b.setClass_D(this);
    }
}

d.addToMyArray(b);
d.addToMyArray(c);
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm. For some reason I thought Hibernate did the relationship automatically...